# Comparing Model in Razor C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm finally starting to learn MVC 3 with Razor. I've a problem with checking which model i'm passing along.

I need to convert this 3 kind of MVC 2 example code to Razor/MVC 3:

```
<li class="<%= Model is FooModel ? "active" : null %>"><a href="<%= Url.Action("Foo") %>Foo</a></li>
<li class="<%= Model is DooModel || Model is BooModel ? "selected" : null %>"><a href="<%= Url.Action("Doo") %>">Doo</a></li>


 <% if (Model is FooModel){ %>Foo<% } else if(Model is DooModel){ %>Doo<% } %>


 <% if (Model is FooModel)
    Html.RenderPartial("Foo");
    else if(Model is DooModel)
     Html.RenderPartial("Doo"); %>
```

Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: so what part of it are you having a problem with?

Comment: All 3 parts. I need to convert it to Razor based code.
Atm i'm trying with for example: "<li class="@(Model is FooModel) ? 'active' : null }"><a href="@Url.Action("Foo")">Foo</a></li>"  Which isnt working so good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<li class="@(Model is FooModel ? "")"><a href="@(Url.Action("Foo"))">Foo</a></li>
<li class="@(Model is DooModel || Model is BooModel ? "selected")>
       <a href="@(Url.Action("Doo"))">Doo</a></li>

@if (Model is FooModel)
{ 
    //not sure what Foo is here
    //if it's just a string/text  just do:
    @:Foo
} 
else if(Model is DooModel) 
{
    @Doo //what is Doo here?
}

@if (Model is FooModel) {
    Html.Partial("Foo")
} else if(Model is DooModel)
{
    Html.Partial("Doo")
}
```

Notes: (1) You shouldn't return `null`, just don't return anything. (2) I'm not sure what you want inside your first and second block what `Foo` and `Doo` are and what you need to do with them.

Comment: I think Foo is just text. Replace `@Foo` with `<text>Foo</text>` or `@:Foo`.

Comment: Work like a charm. Thanks a blast!